# I am trying to create a PDF with HTML

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create a PDF with HTML, I am using this library: [Laravel-Html2Pdf](https://github.com/nahidulhasan/laravel-pdf)

The thing is that it shows me this error:

```
(1/1) ErrorException
file_put_contents(../storage/page-1559774905-46851.html):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Pdf.php line 27
```

My code is:

```php
use Request;
use App\Poll_Answer;
use App\Poll;
use Redirect;
use Pdf;  

$document = Pdf::generatePdf('<h1>Test</h1>');
```

What can it be? Thanks!

Comment: Behind the scenes, wkhtmltopdf works on files so it has to save the HTML of your string somewhere. The relative path "../storage..." Is hard coded into the primary function of that library. I don't actually see how that library would work as the relative path it specifies would be the "/vendor" directory by default in any laravel project. You could open an issue with the library or fix it yourself by submitting a PR with an optional second parameter specifying the path. It could be a cool library, wkhtmltopdf is really neat by itself.

Comment: @Emkrypted first give writable permissions to storage folder then check is it working?